# keyerror: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key not found Blender python

Tags: python, scripting

I wrote such a script

```
def execute(self, context):
    for x in bpy.context.object.material_slots:
        bpy.context.object.active_material_index = 0
        bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()
    D = bpy.data
    if len(D.objects['Cube'].material_slots) < 1:
        D.objects['Cube'].data.materials.append(D.materials['Cube material'])
    else:
        D.objects['Cube'].material_slots[0].material = D.materials['Cube material']    
    if len(D.objects['Cone'].material_slots) < 1:
        D.objects['Cone'].data.materials.append(D.materials['Cone material'])
    else:
        D.objects['Cone'].material_slots[0].material = D.materials['Cone material']
```

My simple scrypt first deletes existing material, then assigns for Cube, "Cube material", Script does the same for Cone
Everything works fine as long as the Cube and Cone are on scene. When the Cube is missing, I get this Error:
KeyError: 'bpy.prop_collection[key]: key "Cube" not found'
What to do to make scrypt work even though the Cube is not on scene, but there is one of the objects[for example Cone] included in the script?

Comment: Please provide some context on what you'd like to do. Removing all materials from all objects called x and then assign a custom material, *regardless of context and scene* -> meaning just all objects called x in the blend file? There are so many issues in your code, I honestly don't know where to start.

Comment: `ob = objects.get("Cube")` if there is no object named "Cube" in objects collection ob will be `None`  Recommend googling (or whichever search) "python KeyError"

Comment: My 2c worth is for the most part never use names to key.  Work from context.  The script above could be split into active object and other selected objects.  Your materials could be simply named same as object since they are materials, just like the mesh named "Cube" being the data of the object named "Cube".  This way can select and run script on a monkey or cylinder or spiral thingy without needing to add pretty much duplicate script.

Answer (score 3):

You just index a thing in `D.objects` while using that key didn't find anything. So the method *raise* an `KeyError`. This is a designed feature to let program know why the code cannot been executed.

I personally recommend using `if key in D.objects` to check whether key is exist.

---

#### 1. Use `get` method provide by bpy collection (similar to `dict.get`)

```py
my_key = "CUBEE"
obj = D.objects.get(my_key, default=None)
if obj is None: #Didn't get it
    #Do something
    pass
```

#### 2. Check whether key exist in collection

```py
my_key = "qwerty"
if my_key not in D.objects.keys():
    #Do something
    pass
else:
    obj = D.objects[my_key]
```

Or a better magic method `__contains__`

```py
key = "yes"
if key not in D.objects:
    #Do something
    pass
```

#### 3. Use find method to get index instead of key

```py
my_key = "foobar"
idx = D.objects.find(my_key)
if idx != -1:
    obj = D.objects[idx]
else: #Not found
    #Do something
    pass
```

#### 4. Using Try and Except statement:

```py
my_key = "Cubeee"
try:
    D.objects[my_key]
except KeyError: #Didn't get it
    #do something here
    pass
except: #raise other error
    raise
```

Try statement can be extremely powerful to deal with most of the Error, and python also provide two optional statement block, `else` `finally` to control the flow. Which could be useful in some situation that common method is not suitable to handle.

eg. if you only want to know if *key is invalid* with objects dict but doesn't care if the content is `None` or key is in hash set:

`bool(D.objects.get(key))` will give you `False` even the key exist, `objects["key"] = None`. While the try statement will still receive the same error raise from `__getitem__`.

---

The collection in Blender implemented a lot of magic method that could be call smoothly in Python. I personally strongly recommend to know information about magic function then directly access them without knowing what happend behind the code.

I *guess* the collection are implement as a custom dict class and provide similar magic method as below:

```py
class Collection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.table = {}
    
    def __getitem__(self,arg):
        if isinstance(arg,str):
            return self.table[arg]
        if isinstance(arg,int):
            key = self.table.keys()[arg]
            return self.table[key]
```

Comment: Try-except on `D.objects` is a bad suggestion. In terms of error handling and readability `get()` is the way to go...

Comment: @brockmann any specified reason that I don't know? I never use it in my code indeed

Comment: @brockmann Wouldn't there be any situation that an explicit try except block do a better job than get? eg. If we don't trust it's get method to be bug free... And I always if you design your try statemeny clear and carefully enough, it should be use a lot because it directly tell the flow control

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "bug free"... I personally don't see any reason using a 
try-except block in this case (see my first comment).

Comment: I just provide an option for the OP, since his title said `KeyError`. The first solution come in my head is try except. And the 3, 4 solution is also bad suggestion IMO. But the OP seems not that familiar with Python, so more information provided will be better I guess

Comment: In general a good idea to provide options. However, based on the question code I'm concerned about whether the OP can handle that. Also, I think we should provide best practice to avoid errors down the road hence my comment...

Comment: Update answer to make common method in front of the solution. Also suggest `__contains__`

Comment: I would like the script to work, for example one object is on the scene [of two], for example a Cube. Now, the script doesn't work, because if there is only a Cube on the scene, it writes an error that there is no Cone.

Comment: I'm trying, this what You wrote. If there is a CUBE on scene, there is no problem. But if i remove Cube and I press button with script I have this same error Key 'Cube' not found

Comment: In Blender 2.83 use `obj = D.objects.get(my_key, None)` without typing `default=`, otherwise you get the error message: `TypeError: get() takes no keyword arguments`

Answer (score 2):

**Work from context**

Instead of writing an option for each object by name could  simply use context to run thru all the meshes  selected objects.

If there is a material named after the mesh it is cleared and this one appended.

Simply select the objects you wish to do this to, then run script.

For example if an object "Cube.001" with mesh "Cube" is selected, and the blend has a material named "Cube" *("Cube_material" feels like overkill since it is a material)*  the materials of the mesh "Cube" will be cleared and "Cube" material appended.

```
import bpy

def execute(self, context):
    meshes = set(o.data for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH')
    for me in meshes:   
        # get material with same name as mesh      
        mat = context.blend_data.materials.get(me.name)
        if mat: 
            me.materials.clear()       
            me.materials.append(mat)
        
# test call

execute(None, bpy.context)
```