# Retargetting code using transform modifier "KeyError"

Tags: python, scripting, constraints, error

So to be clear, the purpose of this script I am making is to make it so:

1. The value of a bone in rig A in Edit Mode is copied
2. The value of a bone with the same name in rig B in edit mode is copied
3. A transform bone constraint is made, with extrapolate turned on, the setting changed to "replace" rather than "add". and then the copied values are pasted.

*When I try to run the script below, it results in "KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "CopyRig" not found' on line 18. And I'm clueless to how to fix it.*

https://pastebin.com/y8SQ6aUv

I have read this, and have spent today trying to understand it, but I can't seem to understand clearly why the problem is happening, or how to fix it. I've linked it before for added reading, as well as clarification I've been trying to figure it out on my own and have done research.

[keyerror: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key not found Blender python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190740/keyerror-bpy-prop-collectionkey-key-not-found-blender-python)

I would love an explanation if possible in Layman's terms on how to help make it work. I've been trying and watching videos, but program is not my strong suit at all.

Thank you for your time!

--*EDIT:* This is the .Blend file I was working with.--

[image]

"Relaxed" below kindly provided the answer. It was a user error, Armatures can have a different name in the armature properties than they do in the Object properties, which is why it was able to pass through until line 18. You can see in the uploaded .Blend it works fine now!

[image]

Comment: would be great if you could provide a blend file as well so we can test wether it works (when we change it) instead of lettings us recreating all things we need to test it. I personally would make it as easy as possible for all that guys who spent their spare time helping other for free (and yes, this is just my opinion)

Comment: small hint: you should not use bold font because it can be interpreted as shouting

Comment: Is the name of the object the same as the armature? By default an armature is named as _Armature_.

Comment: @Chris
My apologies! I meant to bold that section so it was clear the main focus of what I was trying to do at a quick glance. I didn't see the need to add the blend for the script since I was so certain it was a scripting error, but I realized it's very much user error

Thank you for your patience, I'll make sure to post a .blend no matter what next time, lesson very quickly learned!

Comment: @relaxed Thank you very much! I had thought it was, but I didn't realized there was another section. I was making sure it was named CopyRig in the object properties, not the Armature properties...